# giving a ring a topological structure?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $R$ is a ring. and suppose $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology on $R$ such that the open sets in the topology are the ideals of the ring $R$. Prove directly from the definition that $(R ,\mathcal{T})$ is a topological space or disprove it by explicitly exhibiting a counter-example. Also, please by a concrete example of a ring describe the geometry of such a topological space.

this is homework, and I have no idea how to do it. help me! thanks

Comment: Well, a good place to start is from the definitions: Is the arbitrary union of open sets (= ideals) an open set (= ideal)? What about finite intersections?

Comment: @user113609:Please note the edit in my answer, at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to consider the spectrum of a ring, where you use maximal ideals:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spec_of_a_ring

Edit: The Zariski topology is defined on Spec(R), the set of all maximal ideals of R, not on the ring R itself, as pointed out. This link : https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Topological_ring may fit your question better.

Comment: So, what's wrong ? Why the down vote?

Comment: This is not a topology on the ring itself.

Comment: @Zev Chonoles: I just edited. I messaged the OP to let him/her know of the edit.

Comment: I guess it is a Risky topology :) , I'll be more careful next.

Answer (score 0):

$\emptyset\subset R$ is never an ideal, but an element of any topology on $R$, hence the ideals of $R$ don't give a topology of $R$.

Comment: Ah, that feels like a cop-out. Just demand the empty set is also in the topology, then does it work?